# Is it possible to dynamically build variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out the best way to dynamically build variables. I have a database that looks like this:

One record:

```
ans1
ans2
ans3

res1
res2
res3
```

I have a function that checks the answer against the button the user pressed.

```
checkAnswer(q, a, $event) {
    if(a == q.correct){
        this.correctanswer = q.success
    }
}
```

The variable 'a' is either 1, 2 or 3

I would like the code to look something like this:

```
this.correctanswer = q.res+a
```

However, this is not working. How can I look up the appropriate response based on the answer the user chooses? So if the user presses answer 1 they see res1 and so on.

Comment: what does `q` look like?

Comment: it doesn't what that needs to end up being is q.res1 if the user chose answer 1

Comment: `this` is in reference to what? Please show a little more code. I think its probably something real simple.

Comment: we can ignore `this` for now as it is not necessary for my request

Comment: Use `[]` notation for variable property names.... `q['res'+a]`

Comment: can you explain with a sample?

Comment: Follow the duplicate link at top of page also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` (square bracket notation):

```
this.correctanswer = q["res" + a];
```

Comment: `res` should be string

Comment: Sorry @charlietfl, fixed now.

Comment: You were correct. I can't believe I completely forgot about square bracket notation. thank you

Comment: Yes, I was waiting for Stackoverflow to allow me :)